# c# shows thread invalid cross-thread access issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, error-handling

My code shows thread invalid cross-thread access in the line
label_mytimer.Text = mytimeLeft + " Sec"; when running in the debugging, but in normal execution, it has no problem. How can I avoid the multi cross thread access, I know the problem is that many threads try to access my textbox control at same time, don't know how to use backgroundworker if it works.

```
private void ttOnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mytimeLeft > 0)
        {

            // Display the new time left
            // by updating the Time Left label.
            mytimeLeft = mytimeLeft - 1;
            label_mytimer.Text = mytimeLeft + " Sec";//Show time left
        }
        else
        {

            label_mytimer.Text = "OK...";
            mytimeLeft = int.Parse(tBox_rp_Time.Text);

            mycountdownTimer.Stop();
            mycountdownTimer.Enabled = false;

        }
```

Comment: You can only access Winform objects from the UI thread (that might be too much of a generalisation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MethodInvoker to run on GUI thread

```
private void ttOnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{       
    MethodInovker mi = new delegate{
    if (mytimeLeft > 0)
    {
        // Display the new time left
        // by updating the Time Left label.
        mytimeLeft = mytimeLeft - 1;
        label_mytimer.Text = mytimeLeft + " Sec";//Show time left
    }
    else
    {
        label_mytimer.Text = "OK...";
        mytimeLeft = int.Parse(tBox_rp_Time.Text);
        mycountdownTimer.Stop();
        mycountdownTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
    };
    if(InvokeRequired)
       this.Invoke(mi);
 }
```

Comment: "Error 1 Type expected "on  the word 'delegate'

Comment: It should be available, make sure you use delegate not Delegate

Comment: Fwiw this has to be written as MethodInvoker mi = new MethodInvoker(delegate {
...code...
});